# Horizontal Index Match (returning column header)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
    A       B       C
1 Fruit   Color   Meat <- Column Header
2 Banana  Red     Pork
3 Apple   Black   Chicken
4 Orange  White   Beef
```

From the table1 above to table2 below:

```
    A       B     
1 Name    What? <- Column Header
2 Banana  Fruit <- Formula should return these values, based on table 1    
3 Red     Color
4 Beef    Meat
5 Pork    Meat
```

Looking for a formula to return corresponding column name in B2,3,4...
I tried =INDEX(Table1[#Headers],MATCH(J:J,Table1,0))

Comment: Where is the formula going? In Table 2 column C?  What's in column J?

Comment: Formula is going into Table 2 B2 and fill down,

Comment: Are there really three columns or are there actually more? There is an easy three column solution that becomes unwieldy if there are actually many more columns tham three.

Comment: More columns and more rows, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the three columns are unique; e.g. there would never be a *Beef* in the *Color* column. In that case you can simply query each column, passing back a *1, 2* or *3* as the case may be.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[#Headers],
               ISNUMBER(MATCH([@Name], Table1[Fruit], 0))*1+
               ISNUMBER(MATCH([@Name], Table1[Color], 0))*2+
               ISNUMBER(MATCH([@Name], Table1[Meat], 0))*3),
       "no column")
```

[image: Three column lookup]

I'm not sure whether *Port* was an intentional misspelling but it does demonstrate what occurs when there is no match.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! "Port" is spelling mistake.  
I have about 11 columns, is there a way to make the formula shorter?
thank you

Comment: The formula may be visibly long but it is straightforward. Nested [IFERROR functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) could reduce calculation load somewhat but I'm sure sure I would bother unless there were more than 1000 rows to lookup. The formula could be written in such a manner as to facilitate 'ease of use' with line feeds (as above in the edit). Whitespace does not harm a formula.

Comment: @Jeeped - the brackets you used are new to me.  What is that called, so I can search for tips on using those. Is that just how you use a Named Range? Or is there something else that does?

Comment: @user3578951 - Those are 'structured references' for tables (e.g. Insert ► Table). See [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) for more information.